# Set of semi infinite intervals on the real line is a topological basis

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Show that the set $\{(r,\infty): r \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a basis for a topology on the set of real numbers but not a topology itself. Any feedback on my proof would be appreciated.

A collection of open sets $\mathcal B$ is a basis on a set $X$ if and only if it covers X and $\mathcal B$ is closed under finite intersection.

Since $\bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{R}}(r,\infty) = \mathbb{R}$, $\;\mathcal B$ covers $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal B$, where $B_1 = (r_1, \infty) and \; B_2 = (r_2, \infty), for \; r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. 
Since $\;r_1 < r_2$ or $r_2 < r_1$, $\;B_1 \cap B_2 = (r_1,\infty) or \;B_1 \cap B_2 =(r_2,\infty)$. Thus, $B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal B$.

Finally, to show that the set can't be a topology, just note that $(r,\infty)$ is not empty for any choice of r, so our set doesn't contain the empty set.

Comment: Proof looks correct, concise, and complete.  Minor detail: $r1$ may equal $r2$.

Comment: More general and less cumbersome to write: $(r_1,\infty) \cap \cdots \cap (r_k,\infty)  = (r,\infty)$ where $r = \min\{r_i|1\leq i \leq k\}$.

Comment: @EWHLee: You want the maximum, not the minimum; with the minimum you get the union.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, that is my mistake. Thank you for pointing out.